# Add Checkboxes to VB.NET WPF 3.5 TreeView

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-3.5

Is it possible to add checkboxes to the WPF TreeView object?  I'd like to have someone be able to check a specific entry for data retrieval at a later time.

Thanks for the help in advance!

JFV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh Smith has a [post in his blog](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/08/01/article-about-checkboxes-in-a-wpf-treeview/), with a link to a [Codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithCheckBoxes.aspx) that could help you. The article may not be enough to get you what you want to achieve, but it is a good article to start investigations with :)

HTH,
indy

Comment: Thanks for the info...  It's helping me start on the right track...  JFV